# JSONException Index out of range [0..1)

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, android-volley

I am trying to get information from MySql database via Volley in a JSONArray. The PHP script to extract the rows from the table is as follows:

```
<?php
ob_start();
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","planet_db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    //echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$search = $_POST['search'];
//sql query
$query = "SELECT FirstName, LastName, Username FROM users WHERE Username='$search' OR FirstName='$search'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$jsonArr = array(array("FirstName"=>"Einie", "LastName"=>" Mini"));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    array_push($jsonArr,$row);  
}
ob_end_clean();
echo json_encode($jsonArr);
mysqli_close($con);?>
```

The result on performing the query on the database on localhost via HTML page is as follows:
[image: user query]
[image: query result]

The sencond element(index 1) of the JSONArray is present as shown above BUT when I try to get the element at index 1 in JSONArray received by Android app client, then it throws a JSONException:index out of bound [0..1). And similarly, when I edit the following line in my PHP script :`$jsonArr = array(array("FirstName"=>"Einie", "LastName"=>" Mini"));` to  `$jsonArr=array();` and try to get element in JSONArray at index 0, I receive a JSONException:index out of bound [0..0). Concluding, I am not able to receive any element in JSONArray added through the code :

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    array_push($jsonArr,$row);  
}
```

in my android app, instead it throws a JSONException: Index out of bound but I am successfully get correct JSON array while running it on localhost. 
This is my android app's code:

```
private  void performSearch()
{
    final String url = "http://192.168.42.16/planet/searchPeople.php";
    JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response)
                {
                    //searchResults.setAdapter(new ResultListAdapter(response, Contents.this));
                    try {
                        Toast.makeText(Contents.this, response.getJSONObject(1).getString("FirstName") + " "
                                + response.getJSONObject(1).getString("LastName"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (JSONException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(Contents.this,
                            "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(Contents.this, error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        {
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("search", query);
            return map;
        }
    };
    MySingleton.getInstance(Contents.this).addToRq(request); // adding request to Volley Request Queue
}
```

How could I get rid off this kind of Index Out Of bound JSONException? Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Are you getting JSONArray response in onResponse() method???

Comment: Yes, I am and I have tried every combination, please suggest a way out of this..

Answer (score 0):

1) Your URL is a local URL which may or may not be accessible from your Phone based on your network settings. Make sure you can access that URL from your phone.

2) First just try to just print the whole `response` in your `onResponse` method to see if you get the desired JSON or not.

Comment: This is the text of toast being displayed﹕ [{"LastName":" Mini","FirstName":"Einie"}].. which means my device is accessing the host but leaving the required second element in JSON array somewhere and my (192.168.42.16) is visible to the desired devices

Answer (score 0):

1) First of all, have you made sure that your 192.168.42.16 visible to other devices on the network? Make sure by trying to browse to it on your phone

2) If that succeeds, try using [Logcat](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html) to print out the output of what you got. [0..1) means there was one object in the response, so just try logging it like Log.d('JSONTAG', response.toString());

Comment: D/JSONTAG﹕ [{"LastName":" Mini","FirstName":"Einie"}].. this is my logcat output which means my device is accessing the host but leaving the required second element in JSON array somewhere and my (192.168.42.16) is visible to the desired devices

Comment: You are logging the first object at that line. Try logging the entire response?

Comment: I was logging the entire response and I got the above output!